# How to check if ANY of a given set of bits is set

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

How can I compare 2 values A and B and if ANY of the bits that is SET in A is also SET in B, I get back a 0, and if ALL the bits that are SET in A are CLEAR in B I get a 1 (or some other non-zero value)?

Example, fn(1010, 1111) = 0; fn(1110, 0001) = 1; fn(0101, 1010) = 1; fn(0010, 1010) = 0 etc.

**Edit:** fn(0000, 0000) can yield either 0 or 1 as this is an edge case. 1 preferred, 0 acceptable.

Is there a certain combination of AND, OR, XOR, NOT operations that will give me what I am looking for?

Comment: The way to solve these kind or problems is through using pen and paper, and simply try possible combinations. Don't bother with the single `0` or `1` result just yet, just try to find a way that gives you either `0` or a non-zero value. If you have a non-zero value it can then easily be converted to a plain `1` in almost any language.

Comment: What results to you expect for `fn(0000, 0000)`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - I'll settle for a zero/non-zero value as a result. The rest of the question stands - How do I do that? ;-)

Comment: @AxelKemper - I would imagine that fn(0000, 0000) would yield 1. Why? Because I am trying to see if B can be changed to match the set bits of A, but in this case since there are no bits in A that are set, there is nothing to change in B and that is the same as being able to successfully flip the bits in B. If this complicates things, I will settle for 0 for this scenario, as it is a fringe case and is unlikely to happen. HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two conditions are in fact equivalent:

If any 1 bits in `A` correspond to 1 bits  in `B`, the bitwise `AND` will be unequal to zero:

```
((A & B) == 0)
```

If all 1 bits in `A` correspond to 0 bits in `B`, the bitwise AND between A and bit-inverted B will be equal to A:

```
((A & ~B) == A)
```

The following test shows that both expressions yield the same values for all 256 input combinations:

```cs
    for (int A = 0; A < 16; A++)
        for (int B = 0; B < 16; B++)
        {
            bool b1 = ((A & B) == 0);
            bool b2 = ((A & ~B) == A);
    
            if (b1 != b2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{bits4(A)} {bits4(B)} {b1} {b2}");
            }
        }

    string bits4(int a)
    {
        string s = "";
    
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            s = s + (((a >> i) % 2 == 1) ? "1" : "0");
        }
    
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: **Thank you** @AxelKemper - While both do indeed solve the issue at hand, I like the second one better because of the explanation that you provided, and how it more directly addresses the problem I am trying to solve, i.e. if each of the bits of interest in A are not set in B, allow the change.

Comment: @AlexKemper - I had suggested a reduction of both of the expressions above to (!a or !b), based on boolean algebra which you initially accepted and later rejected, because the code above does not work with the suggested change. What I would say however is that the code does not work because it does a 4 bit shift inside a 4 byte int, and also because in C# the complement of an (int)0 is not 1, unlike in boolean logic. I once again thank you for the expressions above, but I would ask you to look at the code below and reconsider the changes I had suggested.

Comment: uint min = 0;
uint max = ~min;

for (uint A = 0; A < 256; A++)
        for (uint B = 0; B < 256; B++)
        {
            bool b1 = (bool)((A & B) == 0);
            bool b3 = (bool)((~A | ~B) == max);
    
            if (b1 != b3)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine($"HARJIT: {bits8((int)A)} {bits8((int)B)} {b1} {b3}");
            }

        }

    string bits8(int a)
    {
        string s = "";
    
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            s = s + (((a >> i) % 2 == 1) ? "1" : "0");
        }
    
        return s;
    }

Comment: My reason for the rejection is that `((A & B) == 0)` does not imply that either `A` or `B` are `0`. Counterexample is `1010 & 0101`. Please post a separate question if you have one. It is teadious to discuss that in a comment chain.